# Adding images into header using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to fit an image into a header of an excel worksheet using a VBA script that generates the plotted result. (fit to page, page numbering etc.).

I already have a working script to generate the wanted result (all the text without the image). But it seems to fail when I try to add the linked image into the VBA code.

edit: I deleted all the info and only have left the part where I added the image into the header.
The macro seems to work but when I look at the result, the expected image isn't included into the file.

```
Sub PlotPDF2()


ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2


Application.PrintCommunication = True
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A:$O"
    .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With

Application.PrintCommunication = True
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
Application.PrintCommunication = True
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture.Filename = _
    "\\SERVER\image1.jpg"
End With
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture
    .Height = 1.2
    .Width = 17
End With

Application.PrintCommunication = True
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to which line throws the error? Also, FYI: VBA is not a scripting language. There is a `VB script` which is a scripting language

Comment: I've adjusted my question

Answer (score 0):

It's required that `&G` be a part of the `LeftHeader` property string for the image to show up in the left header.

Enable the image to show up in the left header.

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&G"
```